# JAXB - Map Java interface to 3rd-party library implementation in a Web service context

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, wsdl, jaxb

I try to expose the following method as a web service
`public void validate(Foo foo) throws javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;`

The problem is `ConstraintViolationException` embeds a `Set` of `javax.validation.ConstraintViolation` which is an interface. I use `hibernate-validator` as javax.validation API implementation.

As is, JAXB can't handle interface. I'm stuck on mapping `org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintViolationImpl` to `ConstraintViolation` at runtime.

Obviously, the only code I can change is my Web service.

How can I defined, in this context, the set of implementation I want to use for all the interface I have?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is bad practice.

You should not be returning or throwing for that matter any `Java` specific objects.

You should only expose interfaces that can be "translated" to any platform.

Comment: +1 - In this case it would be better to throw a JAX-WS friendly exception that trying to map the Hibernate implementation of ConstraintValidation.